# c# how to display next WriteLine after pressing a key

Tags: c#, console.writeline, readkey

Basically in my code I want it to display the next lines after the user presses a key. I thought it was ReadKey, but after I press a key it closes.

For Example

```cs
WriteLine("Press any key to display invoice...");
ReadKey(); //this part

WriteLine("***************************");
WriteLine("***  Corporation ***");
WriteLine("Customer Invoice \r\n");
WriteLine("SHIP TO: ");
```

Comment: You may need to put another `Console.ReadKey()` statement at the end to prevent console window close

Comment: DOH! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another `ReadKey` before the program ends

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to display invoice...");
Console.ReadKey(); //this part

Console.WriteLine("***************************");
Console.WriteLine("***  Corporation ***");
Console.WriteLine("Customer Invoice \r\n");
Console.WriteLine("SHIP TO: ");

// if you dont do this, the program ends and you cant see the other lines
Console.ReadKey();
```